# C++ vector Lower_bound function didn't work like I wanted to

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to use the "lower_bound" function to solve 1099. Two Sum Less Than K question on Leetcode. 
I'm trying to find the maximum number A[j], which makes A[i] + A[j] < K, but it never gives me the right index.

Example 1:
Input: A = [34,23,1,24,75,33,54,8], K = 60
Output: 58
Explanation: 
We can use 34 and 24 to sum 58 which is less than 60.

Example 2" 
Input: A = [10,20,30], K = 15
Output: -1
Explanation: 
In this case it's not possible to get a pair sum less that 15.

```
int twoSumLessThanK(vector<int>& A, int K) {
        sort(A.begin(), A.end());
        int curMax = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            vector<int>::iterator low = lower_bound(begin(A), end(A), K - A[i]);
            if (low != A.end()) {
                curMax = max(curMax, *low + A[i]);
            }
        }
        return curMax;
}
```

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example

Comment: What is "solve 1099"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong as `lower_bound` will return the result that is `>=` the value you are searching for.

This variation of your code works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int twoSumLessThanK(vector<int>& A, int K) {
        sort(A.begin(), A.end());
        int curMax = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            vector<int>::iterator low = upper_bound(begin(A), end(A), K - A[i]);
            if (low != A.begin()) {
                --low;
                curMax = max(curMax, *low + A[i]);
            }
        }
        return curMax;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> x{34,23,1,24,75,33,54,8};
    cout << twoSumLessThanK(x, 60) << '\n';
    vector<int> y{10,20,30};
    cout << twoSumLessThanK(y, 15) << '\n';
}
```

i.e. find the element greater than and then step back one.

Comment: Feel like the logic is still wrong.

Comment: @JimmyLiao OK, misread the requirements, change `upper_bound` to `lower_bound`. So now we're finding the least element which is >= and then step back one, which gives the largest element which is <.

Comment: Logic is still wrong output: 1796 expected: 1794 [358,898,450,732,672,672,256,542,320,573,423,543,591,280,399,923,920,254,135,952,115,536,143,896,411,722,815,635,353,486,127,146,974,495,229,21,733,918,314,670,671,537,533,716,140,599,758,777,185,549]
K = 1800

Comment: @JimmyLiao OK the error is because 898+898=1796. Obviously you aren't allowed to use the same element twice. I'll leave you to fix that problem.